# Quais os limites SQL Server Express e MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Quais os limites do SQL Server Express e MySQL? 
Quantas bases são possíveis? Qual o tamanho de cada base? O tamanho dos arquivos índices?

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Express?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Ambos não possuem limite de bases de dados.

O SQL Server Express pode ter bases de até 10GB cada. A versão completa não possui este limite. O MySQL só tem limite prático do sistema operacional que poderá ser 2TB em alguns casos, mas muito mais em outros. Isso pode ser o limite do tamanho de cada tabela dependendo da forma como está utilizando. Tabelas podem ser particionadas.

O SQL Server (incluindo o Express) pode criar até 999 índices secundários tradicionais por tabela e o MySQL pode criar 64 índices secundários por tabela, mas nunca crie tantos assim. O tamanho do arquivo de índice depende do tamanho da base.

Lembre-se que o SQL Server Express possuem limites por imposição comercial. A principal delas é o tamanho da memória que pode ser usada para *buffers* e outras operações que é de apenas 1GB.

A maioria dos limites de quase todos os principais softwares de banco de dados são suficientes para quase todas as aplicações possíveis. Hoje os limites são mais de hardware ou de praticidade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não sei se isso ainda existe, mas se não me engano o SQL Server Express também possuía alguma restrição em relação ao número de processadores e/ou cores utilizados.

Comment: Existe sim, só pode 1 processador. Eu não coloquei porque não foi perguntado especificamente sobre isto. EU considero uma limitação inferior. Pela minha experiência, p/ os volumes que ele é usado, isso não costuma atrapalhar. A limitação de 1GB da memória complica muito.